# Get all course, chapter in one column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Course

```
+-----+----------+
| id  | c_name   |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | course1  |
| 7   | course2  |
+-----+----------+
```

Chapter

```
+-----+----------+------------+
| id  |  Ch_name | c_id       |
+-----+----------+------------+
| 3   | Chapter1 |     1      |
| 9   | Chapter2 |     7      |
| 11  | Chapter3 |     1      |
| 17  | Chapter4 |     1      |
+-----+----------+------------+
```

I'm trying to select all data so that I can generate the following output:

```
+-----+-- |
|Course   |
+-----+-- |
|Course1  |
|Chapter1 |
|Chapter3 | 
|Chapter4 |
|         |
|Course2  |
|Chapter2 |
```

I have tried in this way:

```
select
    c.CourseID ,
    'Course' as table_name,
    c.CourseName as Course,
    '' as Chapter        
from [MstCourse]c
union 
select
    s.CourseID,
    'Chapter' as table_name,
    c.CourseName as Course,
    s.ChapterName as Chapter       
from [MstCourse] c
inner JOIN [ManageChapter] s ON c.CourseID= s.CourseID    
order by Course, Chapter
```

But I am not getting the results in a single column.

Comment: So what's stopping you? Why isn't what you attempted (what are your attempts)?

Comment: i have done in this way :select
    c.CourseID ,
    'Course' as table_name,
    c.CourseName as Course,
    '' as Chapter
  
from [MstCourse]c
union 
select
    s.CourseID,
    'Chapter' as table_name,
    c.CourseName as Course,
    s.ChapterName as Chapter
   
from [MstCourse] c
inner JOIN [ManageChapter] s ON c.CourseID= s.CourseID

order by Course, Chapter

Comment: but  i am not getting in a single column @Larnu

Comment: [Edit] you question, put your attempt in there, not the comments.

Comment: You need to do something like this `select c.CourseID + ' ' + 'Course'  + ' ' + c.CourseName`. Here is a link to string concatenation in sql server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with a `group by ... with rollup` clause.

**Sample data**

```
create table course
(
  id int,
  name nvarchar(10)
);
insert into course(id, name) values
(1, 'Course1'),
(7, 'Course2');

create table chapter
(
  id int,
  name nvarchar(10),
  c_id int
);
insert into chapter(id, name, c_id) values
(3 , 'Chapter1', 1),
(9 , 'Chapter2', 7),
(11, 'Chapter3', 1),
(17, 'Chapter4', 1);
```

**Solution**

```
select coalesce(ch.Name, co.Name) as [Course]
from course co
join chapter ch
  on ch.c_id = co.id
group by co.Name, ch.Name with rollup
having grouping(co.Name) <> 1
order by co.Name, ch.Name;
```

For some background on how this solution works, have a look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ad3f7ded6bda7c5890db08a98a772cd).